# using ARC, lifetime qualifier assign and unsafe_unretained

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

i'm a little confused about these two qualifiers... 
With ARC instead of using `weak` (i.e. if I need support iOS 4) I can use `unsafe_unretained` losing the auto-nil features... the final result seems to be similar to `assign`.

- Can I exchange `unsafe_unretained` with `assign` ?
- Are these qualifiers the same thing ?

It would be really interesting any link of Apple documentation on this argument... I can find only a few rows [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html)

Comment: Very nice, clear explanation in this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9784807/686385

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Clang's [technical specification of ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) goes into much more detail about how the qualifiers work.

But, to answer your question: `assign` and `__unsafe_unretained` are not the same thing. `assign` is a property attribute that tells the compiler how to synthesise the property's setter implementation, while `__unsafe_unretained` is an ownership qualifier that tells ARC how to insert `retain`/`release` calls. But they are related: when declaring a property, `assign` implies `__unsafe_unretained` ownership.

Prior to ARC, `assign` was the default property ownership qualifier; but with ARC enabled, the default for *retainable object pointer types* is `strong`. (For scalars and other pointer types, `assign` is still the default.)

Comment: thus we don't use `unsafe_unretained` as parameter for properties, we use instead `assign` ?

Comment: It's not that you don't use it, but that you don't need to if you use `assign`.

Comment: so if we cannot use `weak` in order to support iOS 4.3, should we use `unsafe_unretained` or `assign`?

Comment: Yes, for iOS 4.3, you should use `unsafe_unretained` or `assign` since `weak` isn't available. Just be conscious that any pointer with these lifetime qualifiers will not be automatically zeroed after a deallocation (thus there is the possibility they may become a dangling pointer). Also, and I believe this may have changed since the original answer was written, but the default qualifier for an object property in ARC is `strong` not `assign`

Comment: I think this response misses the original poster's question, which was about the difference between the `assign` and `unsafe_unretained` (no double-underscore prefix) property attributes. According to [section 4.1](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations) of the document linked to above, these two attributes both map to `__unsafe_unretained` (with the underscores) ownership, and do actually appear to be equivalent. I think the only difference is that, under ARC, one should use `assign` for non-pointers, and `unsafe_unretained` for pointer types.

Comment: You don't really see unsafe_unretained in property declarations. It's either weak/strong or assign/strong for non-ARC. The only time I have ever used __unsafe_unretained (with 2 underscores) is to keep object pointers in a struct: `Struct s { __unsafe_unretained id obj ; } ;`

Comment: The purpose of unsafe_unretained *as a property attribute* is to provide a scarier looking synonym for assign. The logic is that if it is unsafe, it should look unsafe.

Comment: I like "scarier looking synonym" --- very apt description. :-) The point, of course, is call attention to the extra care required around the use of the property.

Comment: @big_m is absolutely right in pointing out the correct response to what the question is asking.