# Why should I prefer the unsafe_unretained qualifier over assign for weak referencing properties?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using ARC, lifetime qualifier assign and unsafe_unretained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397511/using-arc-lifetime-qualifier-assign-and-unsafe-unretained)

What's the difference between the two?

```
@property(unsafe_unretained) MyClass *delegate;
@property(assign) MyClass *delegate;
```

Both are non-zeroing weak references, right? So is there any reason why I should write the longer and harder to read `unsafe_unretained` instead of `assign`?

Note: I know there is `weak` which is a zeroing reference. But it's only iOS >= 5.

Comment: See the answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397511/using-arc-lifetime-qualifier-assign-and-unsafe-unretained

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a property accessor, yes those are the same. `assign` properties will map to `unsafe_unretained` for this case. But consider writing the ivar manually rather than using ivar synthesis.

```
@interface Foo
{
   Bar *test;
}
@property(assign) Bar *test;
@end
```

This code is now incorrect under ARC, whereas prior to ARC it wasn't. The default attribute for all Obj-C objects is `__strong` moving forward. The proper way to do this moving forward is as follows.

```
@interface Foo
{
   __unsafe_unretained Bar *test;
}
@property(unsafe_unretained) Bar *test;
@end
```

or with ivar synthesis just `@property(unsafe_unretained) Bar *test`

So really its just a different way of writing the same thing, but it shows a different intent.

Comment: Can I use ivar synthesis in iOS 4? Or is this only iOS 5? What else must I keep in mind when using iVar synthesis?

Comment: All versions of iOS back to 2.0 support this.