# ARC: Is ivar assignment affected by property attributes?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

It is casually mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8806947/458603) that instance variables have `__strong` enabled per default - does this mean that having this:

```
@interface Foo {
    Bar *test; // implicitly __strong
}
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) Bar *test;
@end
```

and calling

```
test = [[Bar alloc] init];
```

in the implementation file, that the new `Bar` instance will be retained? If yes, will the  `Bar` instance be released at all when Foo is deallocated, considering that the property tells ARC to not touch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try compiling that? It won't work. The ivar associated with a property has to have the same ownership qualifier as the property. This is in the [Clang ARC doc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property):

> If the associated instance variable already exists, then its ownership qualification must equal the ownership of the property; otherwise, the instance variable is created with that ownership qualification.

```
@interface Digby : NSObject 
{
    NSString * wiska;
}

@property (unsafe_unretained) NSString * wiska;

@end

@implementation Digby

@synthesize wiska;    // Existing ivar 'wiska' for property 'wiska' with unsafe_unretained attribute must be __unsafe_unretained

@end
```

If you remove the explicit ivar declaration, then the synthesized ivar will be `__unsafe_unretained`, like the property.

Comment: you are right, i made a mistake while trying this out - i indeed get an error now indeed. thanks!