# unsafe_unretained and weak and assign under ARC?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strong / weak / retain / unsafe_unretained / assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784762/strong-weak-retain-unsafe-unretained-assign)

what's difference between unsafe_unretained and weak and assign under ARC?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> weak specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive. A weak reference is set to nil when there are no strong
>   references to the object.

`Assign` is identical to `weak` except that it does not set pointers to deallocated instances to nil, potentially leaving dangling pointers. `Assign` and `unsafe_unretained` are identical in usage.

EDIT: Oh my, it seems I massively confused property attributes and ownership qualifiers; my original answer was the correct one. `Assign` and `unsafe_unretained` are both property attributes that imply the ownership qualifier `__unsafe_unretained` for their backing instance variables. Use `unsafe_unretained` for backwards compatibility with iOS 4 and `assign` otherwise.