# Unsafe_unretain Vs Weak VS Assign

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Whats the main difference between these 3 attributes ?? some say Unsafe_Unretain is same as weak but in a non ARC env.
And some say Unsafe_unretain is the same as Assign in ARC env ?
 Whats the actual diff ??

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign/15541801#15541801, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592289/arc-the-meaning-of-unsafe-unretained/8593731#8593731, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784762/strong-weak-retain-unsafe-unretained-assign, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669490/3197253), next time you can search the question up on google.

> Assign is identical to weak except that it does not set pointers to deallocated instances to nil, potentially leaving dangling pointers. Assign and unsafe_unretained are identical in usage.

Use unsafe_unretained in iOS 4 or below, or else, use assign. Weak is different than unsafe_unretained and assign.