# How does UIView prevent retain cycle?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, retain-cycle

Subview has a reference to superview, while superview also has reference (subviews) to subview.

I'm wondering why this doesn't cause retain cycle?

Comment: One reference is weak.

Comment: I'm assuming one reference must be week. How ever I couldn't figure out which one is weak.

Comment: The reference to the superview is weak.

Comment: `@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *superview` I didn't see superview is week in documentation though.

Comment: Ok, so it is `assign`, not `weak`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView`'s `superview` property is declared as

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *superview;
```

In Objective-C, properties declared without a different ownership specifier <strike>are `assign` by default</strike> `strong` by default as of the introduction of ARC, however, the UIKit headers appear to not be using ARC, so this property is most like `assign`. Note also, since the property is readonly, there is most likely a custom getter in the source, so the ownership specifier in the property doesn't necessarily tell us anything. It's safe to assume that Apple has implemented it in such a way as to avoid retain cycles.

`assign` is equivalent to `__unsafe_unretained`, which is a **non-zeroing weak reference**. This means that it does not retain the object, but will not be set to `nil` when the object is deallocated. This has higher performance than `weak` (since it doesn't need to be checked and zeroed), but unsafe, since you could be accessing garbage memory if the referenced object is deallocated.

Also note, the property is declared as `readonly`, which means it could actually be implemented as a method that returns a private instance variable, or does something else entirely that we don't know about. Basically, all that matters is that you can assume that this property **does not retain the object it refers to**.

In new code today, you should be using `weak` instead of `assign`.

Comment: In Objective-C, properties declared without a different ownership specifier should be `strong` by default, right? I think it is actually because of `@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews`, so parents don't hold a retain to subviews, because of the `copy` attribute.

Comment: Also, `assign` attribute doesn’t perform any kind of memory-management. This is the default behavior for primitive data types. `assign` is NOT equivalent to `__unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: @DavidLiu `__unsafe_unretained` and `assign` are in fact identical in practice, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14669490/834998).