# weak or strong for IBOutlet and other

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, strong-references

I have switched my project to ARC, and I don't understand if I have to use `strong` or `weak` for IBOutlets. Xcode do this: in interface builder, if a create a `UILabel` for example and I connect it with assistant editor to my `ViewController`, it create this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *aLabel;
```

It uses the `strong`, instead I read a tutorial on RayWenderlich website that say this:

> But for these two particular properties I have other plans. Instead of
>   `strong`, we will declare them as `weak`.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

> `Weak` is the recommended relationship for all *outlet* properties.
>   These view objects are     already part of the view controller’s view
>   hierarchy and don’t need to be retained elsewhere. The big advantage
>   of declaring your outlets `weak` is that it saves you time writing the
>   viewDidUnload method.
>
> Currently our `viewDidUnload` looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.tableView = nil;
    self.searchBar = nil;
    soundEffect = nil;
}
```

> You can now simplify it to the following:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    soundEffect = nil;
}
```

So use `weak`, instead of the `strong`, and remove the set to nil in the `videDidUnload`, instead Xcode use the `strong`, and use the `self... = nil` in the `viewDidUnload`.

My question is: when do I have to use `strong`, and when `weak`?
I want also use for deployment target iOS 4, so when do I have to use the `unsafe_unretain`? Anyone can help to explain me well with a small tutorial, when use `strong`, `weak` and `unsafe_unretain` with ARC?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**A rule of thumb**

*When a parent has a reference to a child object, you should use a `strong` reference. When a child has a reference to its parent object, you should use a `weak` reference or a  `unsafe_unretained` one (if the former is not available). A typical scenario is when you deal with delegates. For example, a `UITableViewDelegate` doesn't retain a controller class that contains a table view.*

[image]

Here a simple schema to present the main concepts.

Suppose first A,B and C are `strong` references. In particular, C has a `strong` ref to its parent. When obj1 is released (somewhere), the A reference doesn't exist anymore but you have a leak since there is a cycle between obj1 and obj2. Speaking in terms of retain counts (**only for explain purposes**), obj1 has a retain count of 2 (obj2 has a `strong` reference to it), while obj2 has a retain count of 1. If obj1 is released, its retain count is now 1 and its `dealloc` method is not called. obj1 and obj2 still remain in memory but no one has a reference to them: **Leak**.

On the contary, if only A and B are `strong` refs and C is qualified as `weak` all is ok. You have no leaks. In fact, when obj1 is released, it also releases obj2. Speaking in terms of retain counts, obj1 has a retain count of 1, obj2 has a retain count of 1.  If obj1 is released, its retain count is now 0 and its `dealloc` method is called. obj1 and obj2 are removed from memory.

**A simple suggestion: Start to think in terms of object graph when you deal with ARC.**

About your first question, both solutions are valid when you deal with XIBs. In general `weak` references are used when you deal with memory cycles.
Concerning XIBs files, if you use `strong` you need to set `nil` in `viewDidUnload` since if you don't do it, in memory low conditions, you could cause unexpected leaks. You don't release them in `dealloc` because ARC will do it for you.
`weak` instead doesn't need that treatment since, when the target object is destroyed, those values are set as `nil` automatically. No dangling pointers anymore.

If you are interested in, I really suggest you to read [friday-qa-2012-04-13-nib-memory-management](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-04-13-nib-memory-management.html) by **Mike Ash**.

About your second question, if you need to support iOS 4, instead of `weak` you have to use `unsafe_unretained`.

Within SO there are a lot of questions/answers. Here the main ones:

[How do I replace weak references when using ARC and targeting iOS 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893038/how-do-i-replace-weak-references-when-using-arc-and-targeting-ios-4-0)

[What kind of leaks does automatic reference counting in Objective-C not prevent or minimize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260256/what-kind-of-leaks-does-automatic-reference-counting-in-objective-c-not-prevent/)

[using ARC, lifetime qualifier assign and unsafe_unretained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397511/using-arc-lifetime-qualifier-assign-and-unsafe-unretained)

[strong / weak / retain / unsafe_unretained / assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784762/strong-weak-retain-unsafe-unretained-assign)

**Update**

As per shaunlim's comment, starting from iOS 6 `viewDidUnload` method is deprecated. Here I really suggest to see Rob's answer: [iOS 6 - viewDidUnload migrate to didReceiveMemoryWarning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674268/ios-6-viewdidunload-migrate-to-didreceivememorywarning).

Comment: you say that, for iboutlet if i use strong i have to use nil in viewdidunload, and for low memory i don't have leaks, instead with weak i don't have to use nil in videwdidunlaod, and for low memory warning it's better the strong solution or the weak?

Comment: It's the same. Using `weak` allows you to save time on writing code (two lines in your case) by hand. But, Xcode does it for you. My personal opinion. I like to use `strong`.

Comment: Just came across this and wanted to point out that viewDidUnload has since been deprecated. This is still an incredibly informative answer though!

Comment: @shaunlim Thank you very much! I will update the answer based on your comment. Thanks you.

Answer (score 11):

You can use weak for objects which are connected via IBOutlets to objects in IB because in this case the objects will be there as long as the superview is there. This is because the superview has a strong pointer to its subviews.

If the pointer you are defining is the only pointer to an object you should declare it as strong.

If you are a registered developer I strongly recommend that you have a look into the videos from the WWDC11 and WWDC12. Another good resource is the iOS development podcast from [Stanford.](http://itunes.apple.com/de/course/ipad-iphone-app-development/id495052415)

Comment: Are the WWDC12 videos available yet?

Comment: Yes, they are! Really fast this year.

Comment: ok, but i don't understand, my question cover also unsafe_unretain, but for IBOutlet i'm explain well, why apple use strong?...instead of using weak?...so i have to follow apple? or follow the raywenderlich tutorial where i write above a snippet that use weak?

Comment: My guess is that strong is safer in a sense, because the outlets are retained 'once more' besides being retained by the superview as children. Imagine you programatically add/remove some of the subviews on and off, at runtime. By having a strong reference, the removed subviews persist (are not deallocated). In exchange, you have to set the strong references to nil in viewDidUnload.

Comment: On the other hand, if you setup your nib in IB and it stays that way forever (no removing/re-adding subviews at runtime), then weak should be enough (or 'unsafe_unretained, in pre-iOS 5)