# Modal view controllers life cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have read Apple's `design patterns` docs, and a few other guides and there are things I can not understand .

I encounter the problem of passing variables between `viewControllers`, and I saw the `delegate` option.
Than i have realize that if you go from `viewControlA` to `viewControlB` , and you need to update some `mutableArray` from B to A , you can post a delegate from B and A will get it .

**BUT**, if `A` can hear the delegate, that means that A is still alive after I went to `B` .
I was thinking that only when you `push` between views, the previous is still alive, but when the transition is `modal`, the previous scene is actually dead .

What is the life cycle of each view controller class ? They are always alive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two `UIViewController`s called `A` and `B`, and you want to show `B` modally, `A` stays in memory. No one says to `A` to remove (this is true until some other part of the code will remove it).

So, `A` can respond to `B` until the latter (`B`) remains the `presentedViewController` of `A` (`presentingViewController`).

About the `delegate`, you could just avoid it. Suppose for example that `A` and `B` as a property like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* myArray;
```

Before presenting `B` as the modal controller, you can say

```
B* b = // alloc init
b.myArray = [self myArray];
// present modally B
```

Now they will touch the same array. When `B` is dismissed (it will released from memory if you have no references to it), in `myArray` (within `A`) you will find the modifications done in `B`.

Obviously this is just an example. And this is not an advice to not using `delegate`s.

For further references I would just take a look to [Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) in Apple Doc.

Comment: thanks very much! so when does A cleared from memory ? if i go from A to B and C ,all the chain is in memory ? and if i go from B to A by dismissing B , so than B is dead ?

Comment: @Curnelious You need to think in term of objects graph. ROOT-->A-->B. If B is dismissed, now you have ROOT-->A. If ROOT dismiss A, you will have only ROOT. P.S. Upvote too if you want. Cheers.

Comment: @Curnelious Obviously you need to look at retain cycles. See my answer on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168916/weak-or-strong-for-iboutlet-and-other/11170327#11170327. It covers a lot of aspects.