# To support iOS 4.3, use "assign" instead of weak, but Interface Builder uses unsafe_unretained?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, assign, unsafe-unretained

To support iOS 4.3 with ARC, I think the proper way is to use `assign`:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) UIView *view;
@property (assign, nonatomic) MYNode *node;
```

Is that correct?  I also see the following in [Apple's doc for Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> For declared properties, you should use assign instead of weak; for variables you should use __unsafe_unretained instead of __weak.

However, if I use the current Xcode (4.4.1), changing a Single View app target to 4.3, and Ctrl-drag a UIButton to the `.h` file to create an outlet, the generated code is:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *foo;
```

Why the difference and which one should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [4.1.1. Property declarations](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) in the llvm documentation "assign" and "unsafe_unretained" are equivalent in a property declaration:

- assign implies __unsafe_unretained ownership.
- ...
- unsafe_unretained implies __unsafe_unretained ownership.

**ADDED:** In the clang source code http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/SemaObjCProperty_8cpp_source.html you find

```
00523   // 'unsafe_unretained' is alias for 'assign'.
00524   if (Attributes & ObjCDeclSpec::DQ_PR_unsafe_unretained)
00525     PDecl->setPropertyAttributes(ObjCPropertyDecl::OBJC_PR_assign);
```

Comment: but could they both imply the same thing but still have differences?

Comment: @JeremyL: I am sure that there is no difference. I assume that older Xcode versions did not understand `@property (unsafe_unretained, ...)`. I have some older versions so I can test that later if you are really interested.

Comment: There is definitely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You've quoted excerpt from answer to the question "Which classes don’t support weak references?" — actually, I guess, the excerpt is meant to be applied only to the classes listed in the answer.

From what I've read before when I was studying ARC, there is no real difference between `unsafe_unretained` and `assign`.

Comment: an answer said they are different?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397511/using-arc-lifetime-qualifier-assign-and-unsafe-unretained

Comment: That answer is referring to `__unsafe_unretained`, not `unsafe_unretained`.